# Exploding clusters of overlapping points in ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, clustering

In my map application built on the ArcGIS API for JavaScript there are a number of points that share a lat/long. I need a way to allow the user to see all of the points at a specific location by exploding them outward when the top point is clicked. The effect would need to be something like Google's MarkerCluster and Spiderfier.

I know this can be done in other libraries, but I can't find anything similar in the ArcGIS API for JavaScript. ArcGIS is a client requirement so I need to stay within that API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See:
http://lele3p.altervista.org/examples/cluster27/index.html
You can download the source code at:
http://lele3p.altervista.org/downloads/cluster27.zip

Comment: I initially didn't think this was quite the right solution but I revisited and realized that it appears to do the trick. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find anything that did exactly what I wanted so I created a layer for it. Clusters points and creates flares for the clusters. Similar to the accepted answser provided by lele3p. Just posted it on github.

https://github.com/nickcam/FlareClusterLayer

Answer (score 1):

There is [an official ArcGIS API sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/layers_point_clustering.html) for this now. However, there many TODOs in the code, so you can really use it only if your data are very similar to those in the example. [Lele3p's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/84249/12768) or [NickCameron's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/150953/12768) solution should be better.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Point clustering now available in ArcGIS JavaScript 4.x API](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/js-api-arcgis/mapping/point-clustering-now-available-in-arcgis-javascript-4-x-api/):

> ... the 4.14 version of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript (ArcGIS JS API)
> introduced point clustering in beta. Clustering is a method of merging
> nearby and overlapping features into a single symbol.

However, it does not look like it includes a spiderfier.

Answer (score -1):

we did it through the server-side clustering solutions and use Esri js-apis to plot the JSON outputs;
pls see the app link:
http://www.bdvengine.info:8080/bdvengine/BDVMap.html

Comment: You seem to have created two accounts, can you merge them ASAP using [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), please?